# Profibus with rpi master and slave

Tags: rpio

I am newbie to profibus-DP . I am tasked with building profibus master and slave network using Rpi and Rs-485 convertor .

One Rpi will be master and other will be slave. I am using https://github.com/mbuesch/pyprofibus for DP-stack to implement the same.

How can I assign address to master and slave rpi boards to use in profibus initialization sequence. It is not accepting the IP address given to the rpi boards[image]

Comment: Hello, have you created the required configuration files for the master and slave? Please add them to your question. https://github.com/mbuesch/pyprofibus/blob/master/example_dummy.conf

Comment: @RogerJones.Thanks for your reply. I am stuck up at this point . I need help on how to give address for master and slave rpi devices for my setup

Comment: I understand your question, from my understanding they are set in the `.conf` files with the `master_addr` and `addr` lines. This is why I was asking you to post your `.conf` file.

Comment: By the way, are you certain that the stack *can* be used to make the Pi a ProfiBus slave? [The project page](https://bues.ch/cms/automation/profibus.html) seems to imply that the Pi can only be a master: *"A the Raspberry Pi can act as a DP-Master (class 1) with the current stack"*.

Comment: My wrong. By the description it should only act as DP-master . have to look for other open source code to act as master and slave using rpi

Comment: No worries, the solution you have already works as a master so you only need to find a slave implementation for the other Pi, maybe ask the `pyprofibus` guys for guidance on this? Meanwhile maybe you could amend your question (or add an answer) to reflect the new information.